# gzip/deflate compression with Server Sent Events on tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, gzip, server-sent-events, deflate

I am using server sent events for streaming responses (text/event-stream). We want to compress the response using gzip or deflate compression, but the browser shows : ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.
Code for the same -

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream; charset=UTF-8");
response.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
number = 10;
time = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  String resp = "data: " + "Some Response" + "\r\n";

  Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED);
  byte[] input = resp.getBytes("UTF-8");
  deflater.setInput(input);
  deflater.finish();
  byte[] output = new byte[1024];
  deflater.deflate(output);
  deflater.end();
  writer.write(new String(output, "UTF-8"));
  writer.flush();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(time);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
String resp = "data: close\r\n";
Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED);
byte[] input = resp.getBytes("UTF-8");
deflater.setInput(input);
deflater.finish();
byte[] output = new byte[1024];
deflater.deflate(output);
deflater.end();
writer.write(new String(output, "UTF-8"));
writer.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8,ms-stream;charset=UTF-8" as "compressableMimeType" in connector properties did the job!

Comment: where did you add this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Compressed stream is binary data. It must not be printed with `response.getWriter()`. Use `response.getOutputStream()` instead.

**UPDATE**

> Shiva Bhalla: Using the response.getOutputStream() with text/event-stream isn't doing proper streaming after the 1st chunk of response is displayed, the request is being failed at the browser.

2. You have to compress the whole stream using a single Deflater instance.

   In your code you compress each fragment separately. This is equivalent to the following:

   - You take a series of text files (01.txt, 02.txt, ...).
   - You compress each of them into a gzip archive. (01.txt.gz, 02.txt.gz, ...)
   - You concatenate the archives into a single file.

   The above produces an incorrect archive. Gzip files cannot be concatenated like that. The correct code should do the following:

   - You take a series of text files (01.txt, 02.txt, ...).
   - You concatenate the text files into a single file (text.txt).
   - You compress the file into a gzip archive. (text.txt.gz)
3. I recommend you to use a `java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream` [(1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) instead of direct use of a `Deflater`. E.g.

   ```
   new DeflaterOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), true);
   ```
4. Beware of introducing a [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) vulnerability.

Comment: Using the response.getOutputStream() with text/event-stream isn't doing proper streaming after the 1st chunk of response is displayed, the request is being failed at the browser.

Comment: @Konstantin could you please share a reference of server sent events implementation in Java in junction with compression?